# Shipping my mercedes sprinter campervan to USA from UK

Tags: usa, uk, shipping

I'm currently in the early stages of understanding what are the requirements for shipping my sprinter to the USA from the UK.

Just curious to see if anyone has done this before, and the complications they have come across?

Also, any help on the price of the shipping/time process would be really appreciated!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66262/discussion-on-question-by-j-king-shipping-my-mercedes-sprinter-campervan-to-usa).

Comment: Of related interest: *[Shipping my car from Europe to Canada or the U.S](/questions/882)* and *[Are there any transatlantic car ferries from Europe to North/South America?](/questions/66154)*